# CountDownLatch throwing exception when trying to await()

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch

I have a thread A which runs another thread B.
Thread A implements a method "stopExec()" which tries to exit thread B cleanly - allowing it to finish some tasks. So my stopExec method looks something like this:

```
private CountDownLatch lock;

public void stopExec() {
  lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
  threadB.finish();
  try {
    lock.await();
  } catch(InterruptedExcetion ie) {
    Log.d(null, "Thread A not locked.");
  }
  Log.d(null, "Finished.");
}
```

Thread B has a reference to Thread A and it calls "threadA.lock.countDown();" when it finished whatever it was doing.

What happenes it that exception is thrown...thread A doesn't wait, but simply continues.
Can somebody explain me why/what am I doing wrong.
I have used CountDownLatch in a similar way in other cases and it is working as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: I removed tag `android` - this question isn't about **android**

Comment: show the threadA code aswell

Comment: "What happenes it that exception is thrown." => What line? What exception? You need to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
threadB.finish();
```

This code is broken: it contains a data race on the `lock` variable. Try resolving your issue by making the `lock` variable `volatile`.